# Camel's ActiveMq endpoint does not consume some messages

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I have two components, the first one sends AMQ messages to second one using Apache Camel(Request/Response Pattern), but some of messages don't get consumed by second component(remains pending. after some minutes, that message goes to dlQueue).
Why?

this is some of my code:

```
    public void boot() {
        try {
            main = new Main();
            main.enableHangupSupport();

            PooledConnectionFactory pooledConnectionFactoryBean = new PooledConnectionFactory();
            pooledConnectionFactoryBean.setMaxConnections(8);
            pooledConnectionFactoryBean.setMaximumActiveSessionPerConnection(500);

            ActiveMQComponent comp1 = activeMQComponent("failover:(tcp://localhost:61616)?maxReconnectDelay=40000&warnAfterReconnectAttempts=1");
            comp1.setUsePooledConnection(true);
            comp1.setConnectionFactory(pooledConnectionFactoryBean.getConnectionFactory());

            main.bind("activemq", comp1);
            main.bind("activemqException", activeMQComponent("failover:(tcp://localhost:61616)?maxReconnectDelay=40000&warnAfterReconnectAttempts=1"));

            main.addRouteBuilder(new MyRouteBuilder());
            main.run();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception", e);
        }
    }
```

AND the RouteBuilder of second component:

```
private static class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
    //...
    from("activemq:queue:Q.second")
    .process(new Processor() {
                        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                            //...
                        }
                    })
    .log("The Reply of (${in.header.Title}) has been sent successfully!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember right the default configuration of the ActiveMQ endpoint applies a prefetch limit of 1000 messages. Which can cause the problem you describe in combination with pooled connections. 
Using a single connection instead of a connection pool for your ActiveMQ consumer endpoint or setting the prefetch limit to 0 is likely to fix the problem.

Setting the prefetch limit to 0 for all consumers can be achieved by appending `jms.prefetchPolicy.all=0` to your connection URL.

Check out the [AMQ documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html) on prefetch.

Comment: I'll try it and notify you about the result. thanks.

Comment: unfortunately this solution doesn't fix the problem.